# Add width="200" height="200" to onmouseover

Tags: html

So, I currently have an image that is 400x400 pixels. When scaled externally to 200x200 it looks pixilated. I've therefore added it to Wordpress as 400x400 but scaled it down as follows:

However, I'm now trying to add an onmouseover event, with the scaled down image.

It works fine for the normal image, like this:

https://y.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://x.png'" />

But if I try and scale the image, as follows, it doesn't work:

https://y.png' width="200" height="200"" onmouseout="this.src='https://x.png'" />

Please note I've left the source of the image out and replaced with 'x' and 'y'.

Does anyone know how to resolve this please?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the :before pseudo selector to show a background image. This will let you shrink down the 400x400 image in CSS. Run this and hover over the element.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item:hover:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400);
  background-size: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/8B0AB3/ffffff" />  
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this without JavaScript.

Here's a Codepen demo: http://codepen.io/hellojason/pen/GZjpQE

In CSS:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  transition: width 1s;
}

img:hover, img:focus {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
```

Is this what you're after?

Comment: Hi guys - thank you both for your responses. So, I don't actually want the image to get bigger on mouseover. What I'm after is: as the mouse moves over the original image (a cube) another image pops up saying 'Coming Soon'. I have that working fine - but the 'Coming Soon' image is too big, so I need to scale it down within the code to be 200x200 (rather than the 400x400 it currently is). Does that make sense? Will the above work for that please?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it will not. But your situation sounds similar to something I'm doing on my portfolio. https://hellojason.net/  Hover over the thumbnails and see if this is similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's exactly it Jason - however at the moment when I hover over the picture - the new picture that flashes up is far too big. I need to reduce it in size by 50%. I've scaled the image in photoshop but it then loses quality - so i was hoping to use the width="200" height="200" html coding - however when I add this in, it seems to break the whole mousehover code.

Comment: Understood. Any way you can provide a link to your site? It'd be much more helpful to see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Two way for this task you can use

**First way using Javascript.**

**Script :**

```
function bigImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "400px";
    x.style.width = "400px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "200px";
    x.style.width = "200px";
}
```

**Html :**

```
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">
```

You can call your own function from onmouseover or onmouseout function.

**Second way using CSS :**

**CSS :**

```
#image{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}

#image:hover{
width:400px;
height:400px;
}
```

**Html :**

```
<img border="0" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="Smiley" id="image">
```

Comment: I think this might do the trick Avanish - thanks. Where you've inserted '#image' - do I need my image name i.e. exampleimage.png - or the image URL please? Thanks!

Comment: image is a id of img tag. You can use also class attribute.